# Python merge csv files with matching Index

Tags: python, csv

I want to merge two CSV files based on a field
The 1st one looks like this:

```
ID, field1, field2
1,a,green
2,b,white
2,b,red
2,b,blue
3,c,black
```

The second one looks like:

```
ID, field3
1,value1
2,value2
```

What I want to have is:

```
ID, field1, field2,field3
1,a,green,value1
2,b,white,value2
2,b,red,value2
2,b,blue,value2
3,c,black,''
```

I'm using pydev on eclipse

```
import csv

endings0=[]
endings1=[]
with open("salaries.csv") as book0:
    for line in book0:
        endings0.append(line.split(',')[-1])
        endings1.append(line.split(',')[0])

linecounter=0


res = open("result.csv","w")

with open('total.csv') as book2:
    for line in book2:
        # if not header line:

        l=line.split(',')[0]
        for linecounter in range(0,endings1.__len__()):            
            if( l == endings1[linecounter]):
                res.writelines(line.replace("\n","") +','+str(endings0[linecounter]))


print("done")
```

Comment: Good question, but what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you considered using a database?

Comment: I updates the question by adding the code, but i'm missing the last line (3,c,black,'') and i'm not sure if this is the best way to do it

Comment: Add the piece of code you tried to the question

Comment: Why `import csv`, when you don't even use it?

Comment: The concern here is that ID doesn't seem to be unique (ex: 2 shows up multiple times in the list). Do these values have  a unique identifier?

Comment: In the file they are not unique, but i'm inserting this file into a database where the id is a combinition of two fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of things wrong with what you're doing

1. You should *really* **really** be using the classes in the `csv` module to read and write csv files. Importing the module isn't enough. You actually need to call its functions
2. You should never find yourself typing `endings1.__len__()`. Use `len(endings1)` instead
3. You should never find yourself typing `for linecounter in range(0,len(endings1))`.
   Use either `for linecounter, _ in enumerate(endings1)`,
   or better yet `for end1, end2 in zip(endings1, endings2)`
4. A dictionary is a much better data structure for lookup than a pair of parallel lists. To quote [pike](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~adnan/pike.html):

   > If you've chosen the right data structures and organized things well, the algorithms will almost always be self-evident.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
import csv

with open('second.csv') as f:
    # look, a builtin to read csv file lines as dictionaries!
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    # build a mapping of id to field3
    id_to_field3 = {row['ID']: row['field3'] for row in reader}

# you can put more than one open inside a with statement
with open('first.csv') as f, open('result.csv', 'o') as fo:
    # csv even has a class to write files!
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    res = csv.DictWriter(fo, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames + ['field3'])

    res.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        # .get returns its second argument if there was no match
        row['field3'] = id_to_field3.get(row['ID'], '')
        res.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a high-level solution for you.
Deserialize your first CSV into `dict1` mapping ID to a list containing a list containing field1 and field2.
Deserialize your second CSV into `dict2` mapping ID to field3.

for each (id, list) in `dict1`, do `list.append(dict2.setdefault(id, ''))`. Now serialize it back into CSV using whatever serializer you were using before.

I used dictionary's `setdefault` because I noticed that ID 3 is in the first CSV file but not the second.

Comment: _"whatever serializer you were using before"_ - that'll be that well known robust csv interface, the raw text stream then...